# Why does == and equals produce different results?

Tags: reflection, kotlin

Executing the following code:

```
inline fun <reified R> foobar() {
    println(R::class == Double::class)
    println(R::class.equals(Double::class))
}

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    foobar<Double>()
}
```

Produces the following output:

```
false
true
```

Why is there a difference between == and equals in this case? IntelliJ itself is suggesting that I replace the equals call with ==. Also, I could have sworn this code using == was working in the past.

Using kotlin version `1.1.0-rc91`

Comment: Probably a relevant issue with code generation for class tokens of reified type parameters: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-17879

Comment: Please check whether a newer version of Kotlin has this behavior.

Comment: Thanks - yes it seems like it's a known bug: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-17748  Post as an answer and I'll accept it.

Comment: Confirmed the same behavior exists in Kotlin 1.1.2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This behavior is a known issue in code generation for class tokens of reified type parameters, it's tracked here: [KT-17748](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-17748).